# override dispatchTouchEvent cancels onItemClick in row

Tags: android, listview, row, gesture, onitemclick

I'm override dispatchTouchEvent in my Row Class.

```
 @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    my code...
 }
```

But now don't call method `onItemClick` in adapter, because `dispatchTouchEvent` do my actions and return `true`.

How and where could i define what action i have to do on user action?
I just wan't do `onItemClick` if user tap and `dispatchTouchEvent` if user pan.

Maybe i could define what action is that right in `dispatchTouchEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

         if(isPanningDetect){
             return true;
         }else{
             return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event); 
         }
     }
```

Comment: What is isPanningDetect? :)

Comment: you need to code for that in this method by putting geture detector on it